# Get the most accurate request time from Laravel to be used in the frontend

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I need to get an accurate timestamp of the request in order to then calculate the session end time

I need the timestamp in the layout to be available globally for some JS script, so right now I store it in the layout file:

```
// layout.blade.php

<div id="request-timestamp" data-request-timestamp="{{ now()->timestamp }}"></div>
```

Then I can access it using JS:

```
const requestTimestamp = document.getElementById("request-timestamp").dataset.requestTimestamp;
```

But, is there a way to get a more accurate timestamp to the time where Laravel actually saves the session time? Because in my app, there are a few DB connections before it actually gets to the frontend, so it might be less accurate.

Can I somehow send the request timestamp to the layout file in a more accurate way?

Answer (score 2):

To ensure that the timestamp is as close as possible to the server-side request processing, you can get it in the controller and pass it directly to the view.

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $requestTimestamp = now()->timestamp;
    
    return view('your_view', compact('requestTimestamp'));
}
```

**Script**

```
<script>
    const requestTimestamp = {{ $requestTimestamp }};
</script>
```

Comment: thank you, but the problem is it's not any view, I need it on every view that's why I put it in the layout file. Is there any way to do it without a Controller?

Comment: maybe create a middleware that passes the requestTimestamp variable to every view that is been renderd, idk that is how i would do it

Comment: If you need this `$requestTimestamp` on _every_ (or specific) views, you can use a View Composer: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/views#view-composers

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the `LARAVEL_START` constant that is defined in the `public/index.php` file, which returns the unix timestamp:

```
// public/index.php

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
```

And then set it in a div:

```
 <div id="request-timestamp" data-request-timestamp="{{ LARAVEL_START }}"></div>
```

That works pretty well.